# Missing files when compiled to WAR

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, war

I have quite an interesting issue. I'm running maven to compile my Servlet site into a single WAR File. This works completely fine on my local machine; and even when I change my deployment settings to use just the war file, it works fine. However, when I deploy the WAR file to the server, I'm getting 404 errors. I'm no expert with WAR files, so is there some sort of internal file that specifies the location of resources that I need to look at?

Comment: Since a WAR is an archive, it might be necessary to access the resource an an [tag:embedded-resource].

Comment: could you be more specific on the 404 errors? what are the exceptions that are causing them?

Comment: @benjiman It's in Chrome, so all I'm seeing is that the file can not be found when I deploy the WAR file to an external server. I've just cd'd through the WAR file and I can see the files that are there. The files that I am missing are two javascript files, which is very odd, because there are other javascript files and they're getting loaded fine?

Answer (score 0):

First try to unzip your war (wars, jars, ears are zip files) and see if your files are actually there, verify if your unzipped war contains:

- dir  WEB-INF
- file WEB-INF/web.xml
- dir  WEB-INF/lib with the jars your aplication depends on
- dir  WEB-INF/classes with *.class files, where your servlets and related classes are supposed to be (if you have decided to have them there and not in a jar in WEB-INF/lib)
- static resources in the root directory

You could make your conclusions of what is missing in your war.

You could also try to build your own war manually (creating a zip file with the structure I mentioned above and renaming it as *.war) if you have problems with doing it by your IDE's options